# Hibernate Stored Procedure invocation leads to OutOfMemory

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures, large-data

I am using Hibernate's named Query to execute a stored procedure returning a very large dataset ( over 2 million rows ) The DB is Oracle 11g

for instance: 
    `Query query = session.getNamedQuery(procName);`

I know from the hibernate documentation, you cannot use setFirstResult/setMaxResult as stated on 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html.

All is well, on a smaller dataset like 100,000 rows. However, as soon as I test with a 1,000,000 I get the OutOfMemory error.

From the query object, I get a listIterator. I assumed that the data was only fetched once, I iterate over the listiterator ( `query.list().listIterator()`)

I do not have a 2nd level cache configured.
Will these settings help at all, when dealing with an Oracle Stored Procedure.

`query.setCacheMode(org.hibernate.CacheMode.IGNORE);
query.setFetchSize(1000);

query.scroll(org.hibernate.ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);`

Basically, how do I manage large dataset retrieval using stored procs in Hibernate.

Million thanks

Comment: why are you attempting to return 2 million rows? Suggest you process in batches.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on how you handle the data returned from the query. If you treat it as a typical query--that is, call list() on it and store the result in a Collection--then you're going to bust your memory limit with that many rows. The key is to get and process them in batches. I believe the typical way of doing so with Hibernate is getting the results as a [ScrollableResults](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html) and remembering to [flush()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush%28%29) and [clear()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#clear%28%29) the session periodically since it acts as the first-level cache and will store all the objects being loaded. Look around for descriptions of batch processing in Hibernate, but be careful not to get confused with Hibernate's [batch fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-batch) and related concepts. They're two different animals.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is less one of Hibernate than one of memory usage.  I had a similar situation where a JMS message worked fine with a small amount of data, then everything blew up with more.  Since I doubt you need all 2mm records in memory at once, see if you can get the stored proc updated to take a limit and an offset so that it can return slices of data as opposed to only the whole dataset.